# How to improve the Postgre SQL without SQL injection (LIKE %)

Tags: python, postgresql

How to improve PostgreSQL without SQL injection (LIKE %)

```
cur.execute("SELECT officialid from OFFICIAL WHERE username LIKE '%" + searchString + "%'")

sql = "UPDATE EVENT SET eventname = '%s', sportid = %d, referee = %d, judge = %d, medalgiver = %d " \
       "WHERE eventid = %s" % (event_name, s[0][0], r[0][0], j[0][0], m[0][0], event_id)
cur.execute(sql)
```

Comment: This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902408/how-to-use-variables-in-sql-statement-in-python) may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass a tuple of arguments to `execute()` function as a second argument and use `%s` placeholder(s) in query string. Something like this:

```py
sql = "UPDATE EVENT SET eventname = %s, sportid = %s, referee = %s, judge = %s, medalgiver = %s " \
       "WHERE eventid = %s"
cur.execute(sql, (event_name, s[0][0], r[0][0], j[0][0], m[0][0], event_id))
```